# LibGDX Screen Resize with ClickListener

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to create a simple platformer game using Java and LibGDX.

However, whenever I resize the menu screen, I have issues with my ClickListeners. The ClickListeners are not 'listening' at the right place in the screen.

I have a feeling that `camera.unproject();` might work but I don't know where to implement it.

I have looked at many questions on Stack Overflow but have not found an answer that works.

Here is my code:

```
package uk.threepp.scrollfusion.screen;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Table;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.StretchViewport;
import uk.threepp.scrollfusion.Const;
import uk.threepp.scrollfusion.ScrollFusionMain;
import uk.threepp.scrollfusion.transition.Animation;
import uk.threepp.scrollfusion.transition.TransitionScreenScene2D;

public class ScreenMenuMain extends TransitionScreenScene2D {

    //region Variable Declarations
    private ScrollFusionMain game;

    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Table menuTable;
    private Music music;

    private Skin menuSkin;

    private TextButton
            buttonPlay,
            buttonExit;
    //endregion

    public ScreenMenuMain(final ScrollFusionMain g) {

        game = g;

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, Const.SCREEN_WIDTH, Const.SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        stage = new Stage(
                    new StretchViewport(
                        1280, 720, cam),
                game.batch);

        TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas("ui/MenuButton.pack");
        menuSkin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("ui/MenuButton.json"), atlas);

        menuTable = new Table(menuSkin);
        menuTable.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        buttonPlay = new TextButton("Play", menuSkin);
        buttonExit = new TextButton("Exit", menuSkin);
        Label title = new Label("Scroll Fusion", menuSkin);

        //region Button Listeners
        buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                //TransitionHandler.transitionFadeOutToScreen(stage, Const.TRANSITION_SPEED, game, new ScreenGame(game));
                game.setScreen(new ScreenGame(game));
                dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                buttonPlay.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                buttonPlay.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        });

        buttonExit.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }

            @Override
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                buttonExit.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor) {
                buttonExit.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        });
        //endregion

        menuTable.add(title).padBottom(40).row();
        menuTable.add(buttonPlay).row();
        menuTable.add(buttonExit).row();

        menuTable.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(menuTable);

        music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music/Music01.wav"));

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    //region Methods from Screen Interface
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();

        transitionUpdate(delta);
        Gdx.app.log("FPS", String.valueOf(1/delta));

        menuTable.getCell(buttonPlay);
    }




    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        stage.getViewport().update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
        menuTable.setClip(true);
        menuTable.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }




    @Override
    public void show() {
        music.setLooping(true);
        music.play();
        addTransition(Animation.fadeIn, Const.TRANSITION_SPEED);
    }




    @Override
    public void hide() {
    }




    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }




    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }




    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        music.dispose();
        menuSkin.dispose();
    }
    //endregion
}
```

Comment: 3++ has recently found the solution. IntelliJ IDEA needed a project resync.

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in your title.  If you believe the issue to be entirely environmental, feel free to remove the question.  If you feel that others can benefit from this, contribute an answer and accept it.

Comment: OK, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently solved the solution.

IntelliJ IDEA just needed a refresh. If this happens to you, modify your `build.gradle` file (e.g. add a random line break then delete it).

The software will then come up with a prompt to resync your `gradle` project files; click 'Yes'.

Answer (score -1):

In your `resize()` method, try updating the stage viewport **after** `menuTable.setSize()` instead of before.

Comment: Sorry, I have recently found the solution. My software, IntelliJ IDEA, just needed a project resync and then it was all working... but thanks anyway.